# same R code for counting delimited items, different result. Why?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df in which one column contains multiple semicolon-delimited items for each row. I want to write a new column that counts the number of items.

```
df <- mutate(df, n_items = count.fields(textConnection(column_name), sep = ";"))
```

Works great!

If I read in a new df - we'll call it df2 - that is a subset of the original, and try the same thing:

```
df2 <- mutate(df2, n_items = count.fields(textConnection(column_name), sep = ";"))
```

I now get an error:

problem with mutate(), input n_items. X Input "n_items" can't be recylced to size 2296. Input "n_items" must be size 2296 or 1, not 2294.

I have no idea why this is happening, but there are 2296 rows in the df. I tried remaking the .csv and re-reading it in to R, same error. The code is re-loaded from history, so I don't think it's likely to be a typo.  all the items in df2 were also in df. Column names are the same. Hoping someone can point to the source of the error, and how to handle it. Thanks in advance.

eta sample data:

```
a <- c(10000001, 10000002, 10000003, 10000004, 10000005, 10000006, 10000007, 10000008, 10000009)
b <- c("AB100201; CD200000; CD300000", "AB200000", "AB300000; CD100001", "CD100001; EF200000", "CD100001; CD111111; CD222222; CD333333", "AB333333; EF111111; CD200000", "DC300003; AB200101; EF111111", "BA001000; EF111111", "CD2000000; EF111111; CD100001; AB300003")
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

Comment: Check the underlying data with `str(df)` and `str(df2)`. One of them might be factors.

Comment: Good thought. But both are strings (chr)

Comment: More information (sample data) needs to be provided to offer anything more than speculation.  Try the function in steps and confirm you are getting the expected results.  Does `textConnection(column_name)` return an array with a length of 2296?  What about `count.fields(textConnection(column_name), sep = ";")`?

Comment: textConnection(df$column_name) returns the same information as textConnection(df2$column_name). I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to count the array length.

Comment: Are there any zero length strings?  Check `nrow(df)`, `nrow(df2)`, `length(count.fields(textConnection(df$column_name), sep = ';'))`, and `length(count.fields(textConnection(df2$column_name), sep = ';'))`

Comment: length(count.fields(textConnection(df2$column_name), sep = ";")) returns length = 2294 instead of 2296. OTOH nrow(df2) returns 2296.  Something seems to be wrong with row 2294 or 2295 of df2.  If I load the df up in Excel and look visually, there are no weird characters.  Looks like strings of the correct format separated by ;

Comment: The website is complaining about "extended discussions in comments".  Looks like you found the problem and need to look at those specific rows in R to see what is going on.  I can be reached in chat if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the complexity of textConnection by performing the count via sapply:

```
a <- c(10000001, 10000002, 10000003, 10000004, 10000005, 10000006, 10000007, 10000008, 10000009)
b <- c("AB100201; CD200000; CD300000", "AB200000", "AB300000; CD100001", "CD100001; EF200000", "CD100001; CD111111; CD222222; CD333333", "AB333333; EF111111; CD200000", "DC300003; AB200101; EF111111", "BA001000; EF111111", "CD2000000; EF111111; CD100001; AB300003")
df <- data.frame(a,b)

df$n_items <- sapply(df$b, function(x)(length(unlist(strsplit(x, ';')))))
```

Generates:

```
         a                                       b n_items
1 10000001            AB100201; CD200000; CD300000       3
2 10000002                                AB200000       1
3 10000003                      AB300000; CD100001       2
4 10000004                      CD100001; EF200000       2
5 10000005  CD100001; CD111111; CD222222; CD333333       4
6 10000006            AB333333; EF111111; CD200000       3
7 10000007            DC300003; AB200101; EF111111       3
8 10000008                      BA001000; EF111111       2
9 10000009 CD2000000; EF111111; CD100001; AB300003       4
```